# Program runs from CD but not from image (.iso file) of same CD

Tags: iso-image

I got a language course on CD ROM from the library. On holiday, we want to bring a mini laptop without a CD drive so I converted the CD to .iso.

Now, I can mount the .iso just fine but when I try to run it, it says

**"The program needs to be run from CD. Thank you."**

Does anybody know of any way to fix this?

Comment: Circumventing copy-protection is off-topic here. Why don’t you just contact the manufacturer? That being said, what tool did you use to mount the image?

Comment: I used Virtual CloneDrive.

Comment: Before people jump to conclusions and close your question, are you just guessing that the issue might be copy-protection or do you know for sure?  If it was copy protection, I wouldn't expect that kind of message.

Comment: @fixer1234: I'm guessing. Copyright infringement is not my intention. That would be easy enough without the help from any forum. My intention is circumventing the need for a big laptop with CD drive on holiday. But I do acknowledge people's doubts regarding the question. Bummer.